the name of B101EW04 V0 screen power IC
I have a monitor with the code B101EW04 V0. It is quite common on the market, I got it from an old tablet. I plugged it into a decoder board to connect via HDMI but chose the wrong voltage level, causing a power IC to explode:


The first line seems to be the company logo with the letter T
The second line is the number 41
The third line is the number 121

I searched Google, ChatGPT but still can't find it. Hopefully, someone who has encountered this can tell me. Thank you very much, everyone <3

It's Giantec GT24C02-2UDLI-TR serial EEPROM.

The pinout matches what is shown in the picture if all address pins are set to 0.

I can't find a picture of this specific IC, but here is one of the GT24C16-2UDLI-TR with the marking 44:

(Source: taobao.com)
Just in case it isn't obvious: The data that this IC stored is gone now, so depending on the importance of that data, the display may not work correctly even if you replace it.

Oh, Thank you so much
